# Desktop Switcher Tweaks

Tags: unity, workspaces

I tried searching for this question but couldn't find a suitable answer and I have to leave for work. I would like my desktop to allow me to go to Desktop Switch mode and then continue to gain access to programs (ie. type, click buttons, etc) without maximizing that workspace in the meantime. It would stay in desktop switch mode and continue to run as normal until I used Super-S again to maximize the desktop I have selected. Is there any possibility of this occurring?